# При debugging выполняется не весь код, в отличии от Run without debugging в C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, отладка

Имеется тестовый код, в основном по теме "Массивы". При запуске в VS code как проекта, Run without debugging (или dotnet run) код полностью срабатывает, все инструкции на вывод отрабатывают. Но если, запустить отладку, одна инструкция в самом низу не выводится, при этом никаких брейкпонтов нет, и ошибок тоже мне не показывает. В чем может быть причина? Вот код:

```
class Arrays {
static void Main () {

    string[] cars1 = new string[4]; // The first way to create arrays
    cars1[0] = "Volvo";
    cars1[1] = "Ford";
    cars1[2] = "BMW";
    cars1[3] = "GMC";
    
    int[] numbers; // The second way to create arrays
    numbers = new int[3];
    numbers[0] = 1;
    numbers[1] = 2;
    numbers[2] = 3;

    string[] cars; // The third way to create arrays
    cars = new string[3]{"Mazda", "Nissan", "Suzuki"};

    string[] laptops = new string[] {"Panasonic", "Apple", "Lenovo"}; // The fourth way to create arrays
    
    Console.WriteLine("--- Array Access ---");

    Console.WriteLine(laptops[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(laptops[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(laptops[2]);

    Console.WriteLine(cars[1]);

    Console.WriteLine(cars1[3]);
    Console.WriteLine(cars.Length + "- get the length of the array"); // Get the length of the array
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[0]);

    string[,] y = new string[2, 3]{{"Red", "Green", "Blue"}, {"Black", "Yellow", "Pink"}}; // Rectangular arrays
    foreach (string x in y)
        Console.Write($"{x} ");

    
}
```

}`

Собственно, последняя инструкция вывода двухуровневого массива и не выводится. Приложил два скрина, что бы было понятней.

[image: Debugging - последняя инструкция не выводится]
[image: При запуске без отладки она же выводится]

Comment: По-моему вы просто забываете вывести символ переноса строки в конце

Comment: @andreymal, можно пожалуйста подробней? Не совсем понял.

Comment: В первом случае система добавляет символ переноса строки. Во втором случае курсор остаётся в той же строке, но сдвигается в её начало, и служебная информация выводится в неё же, затирая то, что было выведено.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, но а как это исправить? Это ведь не нормальная ситуация, и вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: Скажем так: за собой нужно убирать, подчищать мусор, освобождать ресурсы, переводить каретку на новую строку. Программа завершилась, не сбросив буфер в файл и данные пропали - это не вина операционной системы, это вина разработчика этой программы. Программа завершилась, не переведя курсор - чья вина?